# Example code accessing Apple SensorKit for ambient light sensor

Tags: swift, react-native, light-sensor

Hi there:  I've seen lots of examples of devs pointing out that you need approval to implement SensorKit, but having a very hard time finding any example code where it has actually been implemented in Swift.  All I want to do is repeatedly capture a single sample at the same rate I'm capturing video frames.

The app we've built is in React native, it uses VisionCamera to captures video frames at 60Hz and sends each frame to a frameProcessor (in Swift) for analysis.

Comment: Anyone?  Bueller?